# Auto Increment c# in Excel

Tags: c#

I have here a line of code increment number but every I register a patient the `sampleNum` didn't increment. Please help me with this.

[image]

Please click the image. I already have a line of code for increment a patient number. But every time I register a patient the `sampleNum` did not increment. My point here is every time I register a patient the PatientNumber will increment by 1. Then as you can see in my excel 2 RP00 means my code didn't increment.

Comment: please don't post code as pictures. always paste it into your post. As for your question: your increment variable is help locally so it is initialized with `0` each time you call this method. you need to declare it as a static variable outside of this method.

Comment: The only thing I can see that would reasonably increment a number, is commented out.. `ToString("00001")` might not be what you expect; your number will be formatted to 4 zeroes wide and then have a 1 added on the end, so every number it generates will end in 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program that will ask you for the number of patients to register and print out their formatted patient numbers. I trust that studying it will prove helpful to you completing your homework mission

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many?"); 
        int howMany = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int patNum = 0;
        while(howMany > 0){
          patNum++;
          RegisterPatient(x);
          howMany--;
        }
    }
    
    public static void RegisterPatient(int patientNumber){
        string pn = patientNumber.ToString("RP0000");
        Console.WriteLine("Now registering patient "+pn);
    }
}
```